# NodeJs + Mongoose , overall question about programming good practices

Tags: mongodb, oop, methods, solid

[NodeJs + Mongoose code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je9V5.png)

Hello,

I am curious is it a good practice to have a method where you pass an object/model lets say "filters" class from where you can build an query or use it to create an query so you can obtain your DB entity

Something like :

```
let filters = {userId: <value>, id: <value>, status: <value>}
...getOrder(filters)
```

And instead having those guards:

```
if (order.status) ....
if (order.userId) ....
if ....
```

you will have only one if

order = .getOrder(filters)

```
if (!order) ....
```

or its better to obtain the entity by a simple query and validate in the code whatever you want explicitly

Thank you

Comment: Please do not use links - put the code snippet in the question: 1. links tend to die, 2. images are not copy/paste-able.

Comment: I am sorry, its just might be me, but I dont really understand the question. case #1: `pass an object/model lets say "filters" class from where you can build an query`, case #2: `or use it to create an query so you can obtain your DB entity`. Please provide code samples for both cases.

Comment: @RefaelSheinker , i am talking about :
``` lang-js

1. is it better to get your entity via the DB directly with query and have something like :

user = getUser({age: {$gt: 18}, gender: 'male', name: 'Rafael'}, id: 'someid')

if (!user) {
trow new Exception('User not found')
}

`

OR its better to have it separately 
2. geting the user by id 
`
user = getUser({id: 'someid'})

if (user.age < 18) {
throw new Exception...
}

if (user.name != 'Rafael') {
throw new Exception...
}

if (user.gender != 'male') {
throw new Exception...
}
etc
```